# C++ template class with default parameters, and probably metaprogramming

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I went into trouble understanding the following codes:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class PixType, bool B = PixType::is>
class Test {
public:
    void print() {
        cout << "PixType B=false" <<endl;
    }
};

template <class PixType>
class Test<PixType,true> {
public:
    void print() {
        cout << "PixType B=true" <<endl;
    }
};

class PT {
public:
    static const bool is = false; // here is the magic
};

int main() {
    Test<PT> t;
    t.print();
}
```

I have 4 questions:

1. What's the difference between the first template test class(with <> right after `template` instead of the class name) and the second one(with <> after class name `Test`).
2. Why can two same classes(both are named `Test`) exist at the same time.
3. In fact, when the `is` in class PT is set to be true, the program will print out `PixType B=true`, otherwise `PixType B=false`, and I don't know the magic here.
4. I tried to change the second template Test class to be like:

   ```
       template <class PixType, bool B= true>
       class Test {
       public:
           void print() {
               cout << "PixType B=true" <<endl;
           }
       };
   ```

   But the compiler will warn me of name conflict.

I am really new to these template stuff, and got really confused by these lines of codes. And I don't know how to search for this trick. In most articles about C++ templating, they just talk about some basic ideas and usages about template.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Search for partial specialization of class template. When the non type boolean parameter is true the specialization is selected over the primary template because it is a better match

Comment: @Praetorian Yes, you are right. I finally found explanations to this trick [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization). Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Point 1** What's the difference between the first template test class(with <> right after template instead of the class name) and the second one(with <> after class name Test).

**Response** The first one is the main class template definition. The second one is a specialization of the class template where the second parameter of the template is `true`.

If you didn't have the second one, the first one will be used regardless of whether the second parameter of the template is `true` or `false`.

**Point 2** Why can two same classes(both are named Test) exist at the same time.

**Response** In your case, the second one is a specialization of the first one. When you use:

```
Test<int, true> a;
```

The compiler knows to use the specialization to generate code for `Test<int, true>`. When you use:

```
Test<int, false> b;
```

The compiler know to use the first one to generate code for `Test<int, false>`.

**Point 3** In fact, when the `is` in `class PT` is set to be true, the program will print out `PixType B=true`, otherwise `PixType B=false`, and I don't know the magic here.

**Response** As I explained above, when the second parameter is `true`, the compiler uses the second class template. Otherwise, it uses the first class template. I hope there is no confusion about that any more.

**Point 4** I tried to change the second template Test class to be like:

```
template <class PixType, bool B= true>
class Test {
public:
    void print() {
        cout << "PixType B=true" <<endl;
    }
};
```

But the compiler will warn me of name conflict.

**Response**

Class templates can only be specialized, they cannot be overloaded.

```
template <typename A, typename B> class C1 {};
template <typename A> class C1 {};
```

The above is not supported by the language.

```
template <typename A, typename B> class C1 {};
template <typename A> class C1<A, A*> {};
```

The above is supported by the language. The second class template is a specialization of the first class template.

What you are trying to do is provide a default value for the second parameter but the name used to define the class template is same. The second one is a different class template not a specialization of the first class template.

Comment: Nice answer but in point 2 the example you give shows two different instances of the class being created. This is different to the two class definitions that the OP is asking about, which can coexist due to partial specialisation of the second. I.e. they are two different classes but your example confuses classes and instances

Comment: @RSahu Great help! Can I think it this way: in this case, the parameter `B` will be resolved to the value of `PT::is`, which is `false`, and then the compiler use <PixType, false> to find a best match according to the [Partial ordering](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization#Partial_ordering)? That is to say if there is an expression in primary parameter-list, it will always be evaluated first and then be used to match?

Comment: @arcticfox, That is my understanding.